# Holomorph of a group in Sage

Tags: group-theory, permutations, sagemath

i want to calculate the holomorph of a group on SageMath, for example

G=CyclicPermutationGroup(6) $\\$

H=G.holomorph()$\\$

G.list() , H$\\$

and i get this result: 
([(), (1,2,3,4,5,6), (1,3,5)(2,4,6), (1,4)(2,5)(3,6), (1,5,3)(2,6,4), (1,6,5,4,3,2)], Permutation Group with generators [(3,4,5,6,7,8), (1,2)(4,8)(5,7)])

So, in this case $G$ is represented as permutations of $\mathbb{S}_6$ but $Hol(G)$ is represented on $\mathbb{S}_8$ (?) or maybe some weird representation that i dont understand... there is a way to get $Hol(G)$  also in $\mathbb{S}_6$?
I need to check if certain groups are in $Hol(G)$ , but for example if a want to know:$\\$

G in $Hol(G)$ $\\$

the result is False, obviusly for the different representations
Anyone can help me?

Comment: why do you think $Hol(G)$ can be embedded in $S_6$?

Comment: @JefLaga If G is represented regularly in $S_n$, then $Hol(G)$ is the normalizer of $G$ in $S_n$

Comment: @JefLaga, well thanks for your question, it made me realice that i could use the normalizer function instead